# Take value of textbox from page-1 to page-2 using angular js UI-routing

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ui-router

I am trying to take textbox vale from one Page-1 to Page-2 i amusing below code ..but i am unable to do so.

**Page-1.html**

```
<div >
    <div style="height: 400px">
        <h2>Partial view-1</h2>
        <p>The partial view of the content goes here...
        <input type="text" name="reading" ng-model="reading" />
    </div>
    <div ui-sref="page2"><a href="">Page 2</a></div>
</div>
```

**Page-2.html**

```
<div >
    <div style="height: 400px">
        <h2>Partial view-2</h2>
        <p>The partial view of the content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div ui-sref="page3"><a href="">Page 3</a></div>
    <div ui-sref="autocomplete"><a href="">AUTO COMPLETE</a></div>
</div>
```

**Main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../Route/App.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>AngularJS Ui router</h1>
    <h4>This is the Home Page</h4>
    <div data-ui-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**App.js**

```
var myApp1 = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp1.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/page1");

    $stateProvider
       .state("page1", {
           url: "/page1",
           templateUrl: "Page-1.html"
       })
       .state("page2", {
           url: "/page2?param1",
           templateUrl: "Page-2.html"
       })
    .state("autocomplete", {
        url: "/autocomplete",
        templateUrl: "autocomplete.html"
    });
});
myApp1.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
        $state.go('page2', { 'param1': $state.params.param1 });
}]);
```

Please let me know what else should i do so that i can take value of texbox on page-1 to page-2 in angularjs

Comment: Are you able to navigate from page 1 to page 2?

Comment: @PaulsonPeter navigation is working fine..but i am unable to take value of textbox to another page...any idea what's wrong is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes made to pass textbox value to another page

In Page-1.html

```
<div>
<div style="height: 400px">
    <h2>Partial view-1</h2>
    <p>
        The partial view of the content goes here...
        <input type="text" name="reading" ng-model="reading" />
</div>
<div ui-sref="page2({ myParam: reading })"><a href="">Page 2</a></div>
</div>
```

In -Page-2.html

```
<div>
<div style="height: 400px">
    <h2>Partial view-2</h2>
    <p>The partial view of the content goes here...{{page1Value}}</p>
</div>
<div ui-sref="page3"><a href="">Page 3</a></div>
<div ui-sref="autocomplete"><a href="">AUTO COMPLETE</a></div>
</div>
```

App.js

```
var myApp1 = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp1.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.when("", "/page1");

$stateProvider
   .state("page1", {
       url: "/page1",
       templateUrl: "Page-1.html"
   })
   .state("page2", {
       url: "/page2?param1",
       templateUrl: "Page-2.html",
       params: { myParam: null },
       controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
           $scope.page1Value = $stateParams.myParam;
       }
   })
.state("autocomplete", {
    url: "/autocomplete",
    templateUrl: "autocomplete.html"
});});
myApp1.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
}]);
```

If you want to use $state.go
Then make following modification in App.js and Page-1.html

App.js

```
var myApp1 = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp1.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.when("", "/page1");

$stateProvider
   .state("page1", {
       url: "/page1",
       templateUrl: "Page-1.html",
       controller: 'FirstCtrl'
   })
   .state("page2", {
       url: "/page2?param1",
       templateUrl: "Page-2.html",
       params: { myParam: null },
       controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
           $scope.page1Value = $stateParams.myParam;
       }
   })
.state("autocomplete", {
    url: "/autocomplete",
    templateUrl: "autocomplete.html"
});
});
myApp1.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
$scope.redirectPage2 = function () {
    var result = { myParam: $scope.reading };       
    $state.go('page2', result);
}      
}]);
```

Page-1.html (For $state.go)

```
<div>
<div style="height: 400px">
    <h2>Partial view-1</h2>
    <p>
        The partial view of the content goes here...
        <input type="text" name="reading" ng-model="reading" />
</div>
<!--<div ui-sref="page2({ myParam: reading })"><a href="">Page 2</a></div>-->
<div ng-click="redirectPage2()"><a href="">Page 2</a></div>
```

Comment: i have only one query here can we do this same with $state.go.. i was trying with that ???????

Comment: Please find updated code- It show how to use $state.go to pass parameter from one page to another

Comment: i don't have option to upvote twice otherwise i will do..thanks it works nicely

Comment: Ha ha.. :) Welcome!!